# Trying to return new object in place of original referenced object breaking original reference

Tags: php

I am having a really hard time wording what I am expecting to do so I will show the code and the expected output.

```
class A {
    public $someProp = null;
}

class B {

    function run() {

        $args = func_get_args();

        call_user_func_array(array($this, 'someOtherFunction'), $args);

    }

    function someFunction($object) {
        $object->someProp = 'Some Value';
    }

    function someOtherFunction(&$object) {

        $a = new A();
        $this->someFunction($a);

        // Expected
        var_dump($a->someProp); // Some Value

        // PROBLEM LIES HERE
        // I am trying to set the referenced original object to the altered new object
        // I'm guessing this line breaks the original reference, so how can I avoid that?
        $object = $a;
    }   
}

$a = new A();
// Expected
var_dump($a->someProp); // null

$b = new B();
$b->someFunction($a);

// Expected
var_dump($a->someProp); // Some Value

$a = new A();
$b->run($a);

// Unexpected, expecting 'Some Value'
var_dump($a->someProp); // null
```

**EDIT**
Ok I edited the call to someOtherFunction to better reflect my live code. It is called using call_user_func_array which gives this error.

**Warning: Parameter 1 to B::someOtherFunction() expected to be a reference, value given**

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the argument by reference:

```
function someOtherFunction(&$object) {
```

Comment: Ugh, works in my test code above but not my live code. Give me a few to try and find the difference so I can alter my example.

Comment: Ok I made some edits to show my new problems using your solution with my live code.

Comment: I just did which works in my example but my live code sets $args by use of func_get_args() so I can't dirrectly modify it like you pointed out.

Comment: I modified the example again to show why I can't directly do what you suggested @Leggendario

Comment: That's a problem. `func_get_args` does not deal in references... You should think you code in a different way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely pleased with the solution but it's working in my situation. I understand this solution may cause issues in scenarios with protected and private properties. But my only other option was to rework a whole framework for one reference issue.

```
    function someOtherFunction($object) {

        $a = new A();
        $this->someFunction($a);

        // Expected
        var_dump($a->someProp); // Some Value

        // PROBLEM LIES HERE
        // I am trying to set the referenced original object to the altered new object
        // I'm guessing this line breaks the original reference, so how can I avoid that?
        //$object = clone $a;

        // Copy each property manually
        foreach(get_object_vars($a) as $key => $value) {
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
    }
```